# ¿Por qué marca mis variables indefinifas en HTML y PHP?

Tags: php, html

soy nuevo en estas tecnologías y estoy haciendo un proyecto escolar en el cual mostramos videos para aprender matemáticas básicas para después poner ejercicios a resolver. Estos los hago con un  pero al momento de poner mis variables con las respuestas correctas a las preguntas el navegador me sigue indicando que no están declaradas, ¿saben que se me puede estar escapando?
Estoy usando el metodo POST, el cual ya puse tanto en el HTML como en PHP.
HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bacaf2f5fc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estiloQuinto.css">
    <!--Fin de parte de Frank-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="estilos2.css">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Estambres, Tejidos">
    <!---->
    <style>
        h1{
            color:black;
        }
        p{
            color:black
        }
    </style>

<body>

    <div class="contenedor"> 
    <h1 style="text-align:center"> ¡Fracciones! </h1>
    <p style="text-align:center">
        Fracciones en una recta numérica.
    </p>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WutausheQoA" title="YouTube video player" 
    frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
    <p style="text-align:center">
        Identificando fracciones equivalentes.
    </p>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xCdJ49Q_fVU" title="YouTube video player" 
    frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
    <p style="text-align:center">
        Comparando fracciones con denominadores diferentes.
    </p>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5nHDXbmICE8" title="YouTube video player" 
    frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
    <h1 style="text-align:center"> Intenta resolver los siguientes ejercicios </h1>
    <img src="css/imagenes/sumasFracc1.png">
    <!--Comienza lógica PHP-->
    <form method="POST" action="fracciones.php">    
        <select name="suma">
            <option value="repuesta1">1/2</option>
            <option value="repuesta2">3/4</option>
            <option value="repuesta3">4/3</option>
        </select>
    <button type="submit">Ver resultados</button>
    </form>
    </div>

PHP:

    <?php session_start();
//Depurar errores

if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    require 'views/fracciones.view.php';  //require evita el acceso directo por enlace 
}else{
    header('Location:login.php');
}
$respuesta1=$_POST['respuesta1'];
$respuesta2=$_POST['respuesta2'];
$respuesta3=$_POST['respuesta3'];
$suma=$_POST ['suma'];

if($suma==$respuesta2){
    echo '<li>Correcto</li>';
}else{
    echo '<li>Incorrecto</li>';
}

require 'views/fracciones.view.php';

?>
```

Aquí terminan ambos códigos, muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué variables te marca como indefinidas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te apunta Carlos Agut en su respuesta, estás enviando 'suma', pero estás esperando recibir 'respuesta1', 'respuesta2' y 'respuesta3'.

Sólo necesitas 'suma'. Y las variables $respuesta1, $respuesta2 y $respuesta3 tampoco las necesitas. Sólo necesitas definir la respuesta correcta, para luego comparar si se ha acertado.

```
$correcta = 'respuesta2';
$suma = $_POST['suma'];

if ($suma == $correcta) {
    echo '<li>Correcto</li>';
} else {
    echo '<li>Incorrecto</li>';
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por sus respuestas! Ya no tengo ese error, pero ahora aunque el resultado esté mal me lo marca "Correcto", estoy intentando usar php en el código HTML, por ejemplo:
    </select>
    <?php if($volumen1==$acierto1): ?>
        <p>Correcto!</p>
        <?php if($volumen2==$acierto2): ?>
            <p>Correcto!</p>
    <?php else:  ?>
        <p>Incorrecto!</p>
    <?php endif ?>

¿Es válido? Lo encontré en el manual de PHP.

Comment: No tiene buena pinta, pero abre una nueva pregunta para esto, porque simplemente con ese nuevo trozo de código no sé qué estás haciendo, necesito una visión más amplia.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!
Ya he posteado la nueva pregunta donde se ve mejor el código:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/498392/por-qu%c3%a9-el-resultado-siempre-es-correcto-html-y-php