# ¿Por qué el resultado siempre es "correcto"? HTML y PHP

Tags: php, html, post

He cambiado las variables $volumen y $correcto del archivo HTML al archivo PHP, ya no tengo el error de variables indefinidas, sin embargo, a pesar de que en el archivo selecciono la opción que debe ser incorrecta, siempre me la marca como "correcta", incluso sin necesidad de dar clic al botón "Enviar respuestas". Se puede ver el echo en la página, la cual puse con el propósito de saber si ambas condicionales funcionaban bien. Anexo el código HTML y PHP.

```
<body>
<form action="volumen.php" method="POST"> 
    <div class="contenedor"> 
    <h1 style="text-align:center"> ¡Volumen! </h1>
    <p style="text-align:center">
        Como medir el volúmen.
    </p>  
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mWxW91kvchs" title="YouTube video player" 
    frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <p style="text-align:center">
        Midiendo volúmen con unidades cúbicas.
    </p>  
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nhkp6URbX2g" title="YouTube video player" 
    frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <!--Comienza lógica de PHP-->
    <h1 style="text-align:center"> Intenta resolver los siguientes ejercicios </h1>
    <img src="css/imagenes/volumen1.png">
    
    <select name="volumen1">
        <option value="respuesta1"> 3u³ </option>
        <option value="acierto1"> 9u³ </option>
        <option value="respuesta2"> 2u³ </option>
        <option value="respuesta3"> 12u³ </option>
    </select>

    <img src="css/imagenes/volumen2.png">
    <select name="volumen2">
        <option value="respuesta1"> 5 </option>
        <option value="respuesta2"> 15 </option>
        <option value="acierto2"> 50 </option>
        <option value="respuesta3"> 15 </option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit"><a href="volumen.php">Enviar respuestas</a>
    
    </div>
</form>
```

```
<?php session_start();


$volumen1=$_POST['volumen1'];
$volumen2=$_POST['volumen2'];
$correcto1 = 'acierto1';
$correcto2='acierto2';

if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    require 'views/volumen.view.php';  //'require' evita el acceso directo por enlace 
}else{
    header('Location:login.php');
}


if($volumen1 == $correcto1 || $volumen2 == $correcto2){
    echo '<p>Correcto</p>';
}else{
    echo '<p>Incorrecto</p>';
}

?>
```

Muchas gracias por el apoyo y la atención.

Comment: Saludos. La parte de PHP (que compartes) realmente siempre imprime **Correcto** ya que se cumpla o no la condición que pusiste en el **if** el **else** también tiene como **echo '<p>Correcto</p>';** al menos lo que compartes así está.

Comment: Una disculpa, olvidé corregir ese echo, pero ahora la respuesta siempre es "Incorrecto" a pesar de que lo seleccionado sea la respuesta correcta en ambos select.

Comment: @FranciscoCruz Intenta poner un echo para testear abajo del **if($volumen1 == $correcto1 || $volumen2 == $correcto2)** para $volumen1 y correcto1 porque creo que no esta llegando el dato como string. Fijate bien donde usas Comillas " " y donde ' ' .

Comment: @AleBuo Puse un echo como me comentaste, abajo del if, pero de igual modo me marca "Incorrecto" y "acierto1acierto2", ¿estaré pasando de manera incorrecta ambos valores?

Comment: Sí, estás pasando lo valores de forma incorrecta, de hecho, no los estás pasando. Mira mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como tienes el HTML no estás enviando el formulario al pulsar Enviar respuesta. Porque tienes la burrada de poner un simple enlace. No necesitas un enlace a volumen.php, el formulario ya tiene eso en la propiedad action.

**Mal:**

```
<button type="submit"><a href="volumen.php">Enviar respuestas</a>
```

**Bien:**

```
<input type="submit" value="Enviar respuestas">
```

Hay otras formas de poner el botón, pero esa te debería funcionar, enviando el formulario bien.

Otra cosa, espero que no dejes cosas como "acierto1" como valor de la opción correcta. Ten en cuenta que cualquiera puede ver el código HTML de la página, y viendo los values de las options sabría fácilmente cuál es la correcta.